# What is the definition of a "predictable process"?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, finance

I am reading a book on financial mathematics, and frequently encounter the phrase "predictable process", which I haven't seen definition of, and cannot find the definition online.

At first I thought that this was referring to a process which is known exactly at $t = 0$, but that is not the case, because then I see decomposition of an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in\mathbb N}$-adapted process $(X_t)$ into a martingale process $(M_t)$ and a *predictable* process $(A_t)$ where

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
M_0 = 0, &\hspace{10mm} &\Delta M_t = M_t - M_{t-1} = X_t - E(X_t|\mathcal F_{t-1}) \\
A_0 = 0, &\hspace{10mm} &\Delta A_t = A_t - A_{t-1} = E(X_t|\mathcal F_{t-1}) - X_{t-1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

so it seems like $A_t$ can only be predicted at $t-1$.  Is that what a "predictable process" is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process $(A_t)_{t\geqslant1}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\geqslant0}$-predictable if and only if, for every $t\geqslant0$, $A_{t+1}$ is $\mathcal F_{t}$-measurable.

In other words, at each time $t$, one can *predict* the next value $A_{t+1}$ of the process using only the information available at time $t$, that is, the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_t$.