# What is the difference between an adapted process and a predictable process?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus

As the footnote on page 1 of [this document](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2007/notes/l7.pdf) mentions, even most experts in the field of stochastic processes don't seem to know rigorously what the difference is.

However, since I don't have any idea of what the difference between the two is, I can't remember a definition, right or wrong for either of them.

Would it be possible to give the difference in terms of "simple" adapted and predictable processes (i.e. the composition of a discrete-time process with an a.s. increasing sequence of stopping times) as is done [here](http://tullo.ch/articles/the-ito-isometry/) for predictable processes *only*? (i.e. what about simple adapted processes?)

Moreover, I know that an adapted process is a well-defined concept for discrete time; is the same true for a predictable process? ***If so, what is the difference between their definitions in discrete time?***

I would be happy to understand even just this, because then I could take the intuition behind the Ito Isometry to just be "it's true for discrete time, now take the limit in probability and somehow it works magically in continuous time".

**Seemingly related:**
  [Proof that the predictable sigma algebra is also generated by continuous and adapted processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694235/proof-that-the-predictable-sigma-algebra-is-also-generated-by-continuous-and-ada)
[Is a predictable process adapted?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642245/is-a-predictable-process-adapted)
[What is the definition of a "predictable process"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48709/what-is-the-definition-of-a-predictable-process)

If the above two questions give the answer to my question, I don't understand how, soI would be very grateful for a definition.

Comment: Are we allowed to find the assertion in this unsourced footnote, rather unconvincing?

Comment: It depends on who you know I guess.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In discrete time at least, the definitions I'm familiar with are fairly straightforward.

> Given an increasing filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, a
>   process $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is ***adapted*** if each $X_n$ is
>   $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.

For predictable processes, the random variables are measurable with respect to slightly smaller $\sigma-$algebras.

> Given an increasing filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, a
>   process $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is ***predictable*** if each $Y_n$ is
>   $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable.

I remember these definitions by an analogy with gambling:

An adapted process $X_n$ represents the cumulative gain or loss after $n$ turns, while a predictable process represents a betting strategy. It stands to reason that your betting strategy at the $n$th step can depend on the outcome of the previous $n-1$ steps, but not on the $n$th step itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does make sense based on what I remember. Now to figure out what progressively measurable and non-anticipating mean haha

Comment: Could you please give another example of an adapted vs. predictable process? Perhaps the same outcome-vs-betting one, but with a more in-depth elaboration on what exactly this means :)